# `\newgeometry` and `\pagestyle` inside custom environment

Tags: environments, margins, geometry, pagestyle

The case is simple: when I put `\newgeometry{margin=0}` or `\pagestyle{empty}` inside a custom environment, it doesn’t work (but it work outside).

So, with the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\newgeometry{margin=0pt}
\pagestyle{empty}
\lipsum[4]

\end{document}
```

I get this rendering
[image]

Then, it work.

But, with this one, it totaly fail:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}


\newenvironment{quatrieme}
{
  \newgeometry{margin=0pt}
  \pagestyle{empty}
}
{
}

\begin{document}

\begin{quatrieme}
    \lipsum[4]
\end{quatrieme}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, both `\newgeometry` and `\pagestyle` don’t work correctly inside environment. So, how to force anyway a good behavior?

Comment: `\newenvironment{quatrieme}{\clearpage\newgeometry{...}\pagestyle{...}}{\clearpage}`